# How to convert string to a 32-bit aligned byte array in java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

The title itself might not be self-explaining. Let me show an example:

`_test` is `5f 74 65 73 74` (totally 5 bytes in ascii)

However for some reason I need to pack it into a byte array like:

```
5f 74 65 73 74 00 00 00
```

(the last 3 bytes of 0 are padding bytes to do the alignment)

In other words, I need to calculate the number of padding bytes before I use write() to write those bytes one by one.

I can use this way to get the number I want: `(4 - str.length() % 4) % 4` but I'm curious if there is another efficient way to get that (e.g. bit-wise operation).

Comment: Modulo by a constant, especially powers of two, is essentially guaranteed to be optimized by any serious JIT compiler.

Comment: @harold Funny, this claim pops up *every time* someone uses % (2^n), but the poster never provides any proof for the claim. While it *seems* a simple obvious peephole optimization, its not. x & ((2^n)-1) == x % (2^n) does *not hold true* for *all x*, due to javas definition of % operator with negative x.

Comment: @Durandal I know that straight up anding it doesn't work. It doesn't matter. A slightly less trivial optimization *does* always work, and every compiler I've ever tested it on used it.

Comment: @harold Interesting, so which JIT would that be? Oracle, JRockit or what? Your "every compiler you worked with" sounds an awful lot like C/C++, where % operator is defined differently and the compiler has a lot more leeway due to things left open by the spec.

Comment: @Durandal HotSpot, I've not checked other JVMs. Everything else I've checked does it too (obviously all C compilers, but also the CLR). And there's no leeway required - I'm not suggesting that any of them go ahead and optimize it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, though it would be more efficient **only** if you were using a **fixed-point CPU**, for which division operations such as `/` and `%` are implemented in software instead: `((str.length()-1)|3)+1`.

Answer (score 2):

To figure out the amount of padding to get to a multiple of 4 all we need to look at is the last 2 bits of the length.

```
Last 2 bits   Padding   Padding
 of Length    Needed    in binary
    00          0          00
    01          3          11
    10          2          10
    11          1          01
```

This suggests a pattern.  If the length is even (last bit 0), the padding is equal to the last 2 bits of the length; otherwise it's the last 2 bits with the first bit flipped.

This can be expressed as

```
(len & 0x03) ^ ((len & 0x01) << 1)
```

I.e. take the last 2 bits of the length and xor with the last bit shifted 1 bit to the left.

NOTE: If you do this, be sure to comment it well in the code so the next person who has to read this doesn't have to spend 10 minutes figuring it out.

Comment: Why first write complicated obscure code and then comment what it does? Just write transparent code, and you will not need any comment for such small piece of code. And please don't talk about performance - it should be done only if needed, premature optimization is bad.

Comment: That seems way more complex than I thought of. I voted useful in terms of the way to find the solution. But it seems nobody would understand that piece compared to what I'm currently using. :(

Answer (score 1):

str.length() is not the same as the number of bytes. This is only true if you use ASCII strings. If oyu have non-ASCII string (German, French, ...), then the correct way to determine the number of bytes is following:

```
int nBytes = str.getBytes("UTF8").length();
```

Determining the 32-bit aligned length is trivial.

Comment: That's true but in my scenario I don't need to take care of that.